# Outlook Appointment Ribbon window Save Button Event

Tags: .net, vsto, outlook-addin

I am looking a way to "catch" the click event of the upper left save button:
[image]

How can i create a custom handle to this event? (the click event)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can repurpose or override the behavior of a QAT button, but a better choice would be to intercept the [AppointmentItem.Write event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865085.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter where the ribbon buttons are located.

You can use the following ribbon XML markup to repurpose the Save button, it works just fine on my PC with Outlook 2013:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" onLoad="ribbonLoaded" loadImage="getImages">
 <commands>
   <command idMso="FileSave" onAction="onActionRepurposed" />
 </commands>
</customUI>
```

See [Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462633%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: i am using winforms and i am looking for the click event, you the code you have posted here is WPF maybe? how can i use it in winforms outlook addin project?

Comment: Of course, you need to use in the add-in. It is a ribbon XML, not WPF. Take a closer look at the article I mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This sample is for 2013 to 2016 outlook add-in projects. Called when you click save button or send meeting

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Xml.Linq;
    using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
    using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;

    namespace blah
    {
        public partial class ThisAddIn
        {
            public bool Appointment { get; set; }
            public bool NewAppointment { get; set; }
            public Outlook.Inspector CurrentInspector { get;  set; }
            private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
                Application.Inspectors.NewInspector += InspectorOnNewInspector;
            }

        //Save event of appt or meeting
                 ((Outlook.AppointmentItem)inspector.CurrentItem).Write += OnWrite;
            }
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Xml.Linq;
    using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
    using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
 namespace blah
    {
        public partial class ThisAddIn
        {
 public bool Appointment { get; set; }
 public bool NewAppointment { get; set; }
 public Outlook.Inspector CurrentInspector { get;  set; }
 private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
Application.Inspectors.NewInspector += InspectorOnNewInspector;
}
//Plz can you specify where to write the  
 ((Outlook.AppointmentItem)inspector.CurrentItem).Write += OnWrite;

//as it call two time for my function 
}
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.